# Name for the dimension of subspace of support of boolean function?

Tags: linear-algebra, boolean-functions, linear-equations

The support of a boolean function is defined as the set of $x$ such that $f(x) = 1$. I want to quantify the dimension of the support of the function (i.e. how large the subspace is that is made up of these $x$.)

Is there a term in the literature for this quantity?

Comment: Do you mean the dimension of the subspace *spanned* by the support? (I suppose one could alternatively mean something like "the dimension of the largest subspace contained in the support", or possibly other things as well.)

Comment: Yes, I mean the dimension of the subspace spanned by the support